# localStorage is saving html as [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript

I want to save some html into localStorage

```
<div class='table'>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0]
localStorage.setItem("mykey", table)
console.log(localStorage)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gdv60aoL/

what I'm getting is: 
`Storage {mykey: "[object HTMLDivElement]", length: 1}`

What's [object HTMLDivElement]? Is this empty? I just want to store this as html.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You tried to save the DOM object that represents a html element not the actual html string which you can get by accessing innerHTML/outerHTML, eg `table.outerHTML`. `[object HTMLDivElement]` is the result from js trying to coerce that dom object to a string value

Comment: It would be great if you can explain, what are you trying to accomplish here? I do not see any reason why you should be storing an HTML element in local storage. Please be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing up as '[object HTMLDivElement]' because you haven't serialized the object before storing it. Keep in mind that LocalStorage only stores string key-value pairs so whatever you store must be a string.

If what you were expecting is the html of the element, try:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0]
localStorage.setItem("mykey", table.outerHTML)
console.log(localStorage)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not empty, when you are logging, you are saying `console.log(localStorage)`, if you would to see the real value, do `console.log(localStorage.getItem("mykey"))`.

Also remember, `localStorage` only takes in string values, so you could do `JSON.stringify`, to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is not a value, it's html element, use below example to do it.

```
var tableValue = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0].value;
localStorage.setItem("myKey", tableValue);
```

Comment: Depend's, if he wants the html element or value, but i still upvoted, never mind daily vote limit :(

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. If you want the complete block add `outerHTML` to the line that fetches the content. Everything else works.

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0].outerHTML
localStorage.setItem("mykey", table)

console.log(localStorage)
```

The outpus is as expected:

```
mykey: "<div class="table"><p>text</p></div>"
```

If you want only the paragraph element, then use `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you save in localStorage is parsing of a HTML Object. Here you need to parse HTML Object into string and save it in to localStorage because localStorage stores data only in `"key":"string"` format (it means value must be in `string` data type)

To use HTML object as string:

```js
var tableContent = table.outerHTML;
localStorage.setItem('myKey', tableContent);
```

Reference: [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)